# Как задать динамический диапазон в Excel

Tags: excel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
=ТЕКСТ(ВРЕМЯ(0;ЕСЛИ(C2=ЛОЖЬ;B2;0)+ЕСЛИ(C3=ЛОЖЬ;B3;0)+ЕСЛИ(C4=ЛОЖЬ;B4;0);0);"чч:мм")
```

У меня задано подсчет по трем строкам, как изменить формулу, чтобы она считала динамически, независимо от кол-ва строк?

Answer (score 0):

Незачем преобразовывать время в текст. *1 минута = 1/(24*60)* суток:

```
=СУММ(ЕСЛИ(C2:C99<>"";B2:B99))/1440
```

Формула массива. Ввод такой формулы завершается тремя клавишами - `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. Формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ячейке задать формат "*Время*"

Можно воспользоваться другой функцией:

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(--(C2:C6<>"");B2:B6)/1440
```

В этом случае "массивный" ввод не требуется.

Если диапазон большой и таких формул много, лучше применять первую - в ней обрезаются лишние вычисления.

Если под диапазоном размещены другие данные, вычисления намного усложняются, т.к. нужно вычислить строку окончания полезного диапазона (тоже формула массива):

```
=МИН(ЕСЛИ(ЛЕВБ(A2:A99;3)="Сум";СТРОКА(A2:A99)))
```

Это значение использовать в основной формуле не забываем - "массивной"):

```
=СУММ(ЕСЛИ(СТРОКА(C2:C99)<D2;ЕСЛИ(C2:C99<>"";B2:B99))/1440)
```

*D2* - ячейка с вычислением номера строки. Вычисление окончания диапазона можно дописать в основную формулу вместо ссылки *D2*

Comment: А если у меня не пуста последняя строка?

Comment: Изменил картинку, как тогда быть?

Comment: и мне еще нобходимо учитывать checkbox

Comment: Плохое размещение данных. Чем больше отчетных красивостей (смешаны данные, объединенные ячейки... ), тем сложнее вычисление.  Checkbox учитывается. Вернее, в ячейке или пусто, или значение.

Answer (score 0):

Формулы "=ЕСЛИ(C2=ЛОЖЬ;B2;0)" (это для D2) нужно поместить в столбец D, при необходимости его скрыть. В B5 поместить "=СУММА(D2:D4)". Если вы будете вставлять строки перед второй или третьей, то формула в B5 будет меняться автоматически. Строки нужно вставлять копированием и вставкой, чтобы получить не только формулу в столбце D, но и другое содержимое строки.

Вообще, способов есть масса. Можно воспользоваться функцией DSUM (не знаю, как будет по-русски, скорее всего БДСУМ): "=DSUM(A1:C4;"Минут";E5:E6)", в E5 поместить "Исключить", в E6 - "ЛОЖЬ". Точно так же скрыть колонку E. Точно так же формула в B5 будет автоматически меняться при вставке строк.